# Securing/Hardening QtRemoteObjects server

Tags: qt, qt5, qt6, qtremoteobjects

I know that QtRemoteObjects aren't supposed to be used in public networks, but i wonder if there is any way to have a QtRO setup hardened enough to withstand public exposure on the internet.
QSslSocket clearly does not help here, what this would have to boil down to is making sure that only legit request get through/end up being processed, avoiding issues like buffer overflows and the like.
Introducing an intermediary validator could be possible, if that would get the job done.

Second to this, it would be good to have approaches to enforce isolation within the QtRO server for each client. Like something more robust than relying on objectName or so..

Any idea?